# Automate already open Word document -> Save AS

Tags: c#, filemaker, word-automation

Is it possible to automate the Save As-process on a document thats already open in Word? I'm using a OLE link between a FileMaker-database and a Word-document. The Document is triggered to open from within FileMaker, but now I need to write a small snippet (C#) to automate the save As-procedure and close Word. Is this possible or must the document the automation is working with be opened by the automation script ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it depends on what you're trying to achieve.

I did something similar with Word's normal.dot file to auto run a macro on every Word document opened (students downloading work files), so that they are "forced" to SAVE AS their work onto their proper work folders. Otherwise the default is always Window's temp folders. As you can appreciate, if you do not SAVE AS and work on the document, you save all your work on a temporary copy of the file and when you log off, the entire file is lost!

If this is similar to what you're after do the following:

[1] Open Word as an empty document (ie: open Word application without an actual Word file)
[2] Press ALT-F11 to open Visual Basic for App (VBA)
[3] Expand the NORMAL folder (it may be called something else), but we need to save this macro into the default DOT file.
[4] Double-click "ThisDocument"
[5] A document macro window should open
[6] Paste the following code:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
  MsgBox "Make sure you do a FILE -> SAVE-AS before starting your work!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "WARNING!"
End Sub
```

[7] Close Word and make sure you update the NORMAL.DOT file

The next time you open a Word document, the system will auto ask you to make sure you save your work before continuing.

Of course in your case you need a similar macro to start when you EXIT the word document, to make sure it's a SAVE AS.

In that case use something like this ...

```
ActiveDocument.SAVEAS FileName:= _
    "<YOUR NETWORK OR FOLDER>myfile.docx", FileFormat:= _
    wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles _
    :=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts _
    :=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, _
    SaveAsAOCELetter:=False
```

And place it in the Document_Close() or AutoClose() event. I'll let you decide which one is appropriate.